# Database validation for a user input text field in oracle UCM | WCC

Tags: oracle, content-management-system, webcenter, oracle-ucm, stellent

I'm new to Oracle WCC. 
In Oracle WCC/UCM( Universal content management), I have one table named CreateStudent has 2 columns StudentID and StudentName.
One metadata custom field XXStudent_Info for which user will pass the value on Checkin page.
We need to validate the value of XXStudent_Info to database column StudentID, if it matches then checkin possible otherwise restrict on checkin itself.

How can i do this in WCC via out of the box functionality or will i have to create a custom service/query for this DB validation. Please give steps in detail

Answer (score 1):

Is the custom metadata field *XXStudent_Info* based on an option list which uses a view which is based on the table? If so, you should be able to restrict it to only valid values.

Comment: If I deliberately choose to pass any value in custom field XXStudent_Info,since this DB column contains more than 1.4 million
 rows.then i will have to create a service/query for this and view/table wont work .right? 
Can we try to pass parameter in where clause in the query
 and get specific result means single value as the value in column is unique?
Also, is there any way to check my service is working fine i.e. the value passed in XXStudent_Info is being parsed to the service correctly .Thanks

Comment: This component might help: https://bitbucket.org/mythics/metadatamultiselectwidget